# Pass custom Props to Private Route - React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

We have a React component `XYZ` that has certain UI that needs to be hidden/showed based on the route that has mounted the component.

For eg, if the route is /show -> it shall show a table
if the route is /hide-> it shall hide the table.

react-router-dom is being used, but would not like to use state in history.push(...).

Am looking for a solution that can be achieved while defining the routes so that any developer who used this route later don't have to worry about maintaining the state.

PS: We are using Private Route with TS, and overriding the render method is not possible unless `any` is used.

```
interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
}

const PrivateRoute: FunctionComponent<PrivateRouteProps> = ({
    component: Component,
    ...rest
  }) => {
    if (!Component) return null;    
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => true
                ? <Component {...props}/>  // looking for a way to pass custom props here
                : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />}
        />
    )
}
```

usage :

```
<PrivateRoute path='/show' component={XYZ} />
```

Any help on how can I pass props in this PrivateRoute and then pass it on to the Component will be appreciated.TIA

Answer (score 0):

### Props

I am assuming that that the extra props are known and can be passed as props to the `PrivateRoute` component.

We will define the `type PrivateRouteProps` as a generic which depends on the type of `ExtraProps`.  It will take the additional passed-down props as an object with the prop name `extraProps`.

Our `PrivateRouteProps` will accept all of the normal `RouteProps` except for `component`, because we want to override that with our own definition.  Our version of the `component` is one which takes the typical `RouteComponentProps` and also our `ExtraProps` (as top-level props).

```
type PrivateRouteProps<ExtraProps> = Omit<RouteProps, 'component'> & {
  component: ComponentType<RouteComponentProps & ExtraProps>
  extraProps: ExtraProps;
}
```

### Component

In our `render` function, we can implement the `show`/`hide` toggling by checking the value of `props.match.path`, which is already provided a part of `RouteComponentProps`.

When we call the `Component`, we pass down all of the props which were provided to the `render` and also all of the `extraProps` that we passed in to `PrivateComponent`.  We are not having to overwrite the definition of `render` at all, we're just adding our own extra props on top of what's given.  If we didn't, we would get errors because we typed the `Component` such that it expects to receive `ExtraProps`.

Our `PrivateRoute` is generic, so instead of typing the component itself as `FunctionComponent`, we will type the props.

```
const PrivateRoute = <ExtraProps extends {}>({
    component: Component,
    extraProps,
    ...rest
  }: PrivateRouteProps<ExtraProps>) => {
    if (!Component) return null;
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => props.match.path.startsWith('/show')
                ? <Component {...extraProps} {...props}/>
                : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />}
        />
    )
}
```

### Usage

Now when we declare a `PrivateRoute`, we must always pass the appropriate extra props.

```
const RenderNumber = ({n}: {n: number}) => (
  <div>{n}</div>
)

<PrivateRoute path="/show/something" component={RenderNumber} extraProps={{n: 5}}/>
// renders the number 5
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBhCcCAOyWJgBUBPMJAXzgDMpC4AiKVDNgbgFgAUKEixciCAFcYSbAknSACizABnWUgAmwThlnykBIqXJKIq7ACEWAdxVIocqfewBla8BhoAFnAbNWHFwwALQsTlDBGoS8goIwNEhwSsAAbijSjorKKgA8AKIAHjBQKKaqAHxwALxwAPIgHjmZSGVqcADkaISQxjDtlQBkuIJwcF1GZDAAXHCGPZPUtE36cySTrXBDhcWl2eUjcEhFJa0z2yfZ-AJ0sQJdxCrwyWkZ%20tVw%20ce7ZiqHRWQaX44OjlAAUOAOo3G83IM1WvUwkL%20O1aiIEo1GADpsZxHgc6DNnukkM1Wp8UXsAJTVSoQ9EY4CMOCggCE8Mm1M4MAkUGIcGIEgANoKrhi4FyeXzQUixcsnDKxRicNjMbiYDd6YrFZxiBp7FUcKCwNlqVVKsafpiQOlvJiwOkvJjHihYCoAOoeLyg9oAehUXgg1nalIVWrFAH4PuzyLgVUcKT8GMrsRbVHQfftNWGtTMmpptEgMHAYBADTg4PaYF5iCgQEgZr72thndIZuX-CAZqmVJjBRA0OlgCRfL4GBmNdmM0iQ9dbvdHogAfYAHISEAAI3s73BxAJuGIMwFG-sdFNlWl9JyWhS5Rwu5yPuvmZngnn8AAgmAwNuz8N6RLeWZJEcisQM7AcfQoEzLUcjcDxvGgsMciJV4nArB0qjYP0A2sP1CCQKtgGIABzNgxm6NZyANZBdRXNdNygBh4wuH4ywPOAAFY6HTRDZR9ODPC8XiPh9UDbHsZooIOGc6CAA)